# Set.seed in monte Carlo

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, montecarlo, seed

```
#year 2022

R.100<-runif(n=100, min = 40, max = 65)
R.100
summary(R.100)

R.norm.100<-rnorm(length(R.100), mean = 50, sd=7)
R.norm.100
summary(R.norm.100)

a=0.6
C=100

f<-seq(from=1.10, to=1.18, by=0.005)
B<-NULL
B<-as.data.frame(B)

for(i in 1:length(f)) {
  for(R in 1:length(R.norm.100)) {
    B[i, "degerler"] <- (R.norm.100[R]-(1-a)*C*f[i]) / R.norm.100[R]
  }
}

summary(B)
```

When running the above loop function and calculating B, I want that the simulated number of R in the numerator would be the same in the denominator. For example, when B is calculated if R is simulated as 55 in the numerator, I want R in the denominator would 
be 55.

How can I write the R-codes for this function?

And the last thing, I want to repeat this function many times such as 50.

Can you help me please?
Best regards 
Zehra Civan

Comment: Hi Zehra, you are overwriting the values in B. What is your expected output? Is it a matrix with 100 rows and each column being one value of f?

Comment: Yes, right. B has 100 rows and each column has one value of f.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. `R.norm.100` is a vector and it will be the same value in the numerator and the denominator. Your code uses two loops which are rarely needed in R since the functions you are using are vectorized. In your case `B[i, "degerler"]` will be overwritten 100 times so that only the last value is preserved.

Comment: I want that the simulated number as of R will be the same in the numerator and the denominator. How can I write the r-codes? Thanks so much

Comment: You have done it by creating a vector and indexing the same value of the vector in the numerator and the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
B[i, "degerler"] <- (R.norm.100[R]-(1-a)*C*f[i]) / R.norm.100[R]
```

You are replacing your calculated values for each R. To get your matrix B, you can do something below:

```
R.norm.100<-rnorm(length(R.100), mean = 50, sd=7)
a=0.6
C=100

f<-seq(from=1.10, to=1.18, by=0.005)
B<-matrix(0,nrow=length(R.norm.100),ncol=length(f))

for(i in 1:length(f)) {
  for(R in 1:length(R.norm.100)) {
    B[R,i] <- (R.norm.100[R]-(1-a)*C*f[i]) / R.norm.100[R]
  }
}

summary(B)
```

In R, you don't need to iterate through all your elements, just apply the function you have onto the vector itself. For example:

```
i=1
result_1 = vector("numeric",length(R))
for(R in 1:length(R.norm.100)) {
        result_1[R] <- (R.norm.100[R]-(1-a)*C*f[i]) / R.norm.100[R]
      }
result_2 = (R.norm.100-(1-a)*C*f[i]) / R.norm.100
identical(result_1,result_2)
[1] TRUE
```

Hence,you can skip the double for loop altogether by doing:

```
B = sapply(f,function(i)(R.norm.100[R]-(1-a)*C*i) / R.norm.100)
```

Which gives you the result you need

Comment: Actually, I didn't explain what I want to do but your explanation is solved my problem. I really thanks Stupidwolf.

Comment: If the answer solved your question you can consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark (please don't though). https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this (definitely no obligation in this case).